# openstack hypervisor list does not find my compute node

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

I'm installing openstack ocata following the ubuntu install guide. When I run the command `openstack hypervisor list` I get the following answer:

```
The server is currently unavailable. Please try again at a later time.<br /><br />


(HTTP 503) (Request-ID: req-fc57ec04-58a3-4ff6-b3bb-fd055a7c8845)
```

I'm just getting started with openstack and don't know which logs I should have a look at. So if someone some hints or knows the problem I would be grateful.

Comment: The OpenStack logs are in the /var/log directory. For example, nova logs will be in /var/log/nova.

Comment: Run the command "openstack --debug hypervisor list" to understand the various API calls made so that you know what is causing the 503 error.

Comment: i did this put it seems to halt: Starting new HTTP connection (1): controller and nothing happens

Comment: Can you please check whether all the services are up & running and also restart all services one after another and check the logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it was a name resolution problem. Had to fix it on our DNS server. Now it works fine.

Thanks for yout effort